# Excel - How to order stacks by size inside a bar in a stacked bar chart?

Tags: excel, stack, stackedbarseries

How to order stacks inside a bar in a stacked bar chart by size. I have spend by business unit and region and want to create bars that represent business units and the stacks represent the regions. Now, I would like the stacks to be arranged by the size of the spend and not by region as excel does it. I am using excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the bar chart, you can edit how Excel sees your data - changing from the region to size of the spend, etc.